# Virtual Machine of real bootcamp that's on external drive

Tags: macos, windows, bootcamp, ssd, vmware

So I have a Bootcamp / dual boot setup where my iMac has a bootable Windows installed on an external SSD. I would like to be able to boot that SSD using VMware or something similar whilst natively being in my MacOS boot. This was previously possible to access the Bootcamp drive when having Bootcamp installed directly through the Apple Bootcamp i.e. when partitioned to the Mac hard drive. However when I try to do this in a software now, virtual machine softwares do not recognise the Bootcamp as a drive to create a virtual boot from. Does anyone know if this is possible? Hope this makes sense!

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Fusion/12/com.vmware.fusion.using.doc/GUID-44F0AC9F-C57A-49A7-BA71-7FF0E9BDDD2E.html